# Replace all occurences of char inside quotes on PHP

Tags: php, regex, escaping, preg-replace

How could I convert something like this:

```
"hi (text here) and (other text)" come (again)
```

To this:

```
"hi \(text here\) and \(other text\)" come (again)
```

Basically, I want to escape "only" the parentheses that are inside quotes.

**EDIT**

I'm to new in Regex and so, I tried this:

```
$params = preg_replace('/(\'[^\(]*)[\(]+/', '$1\\\($2', $string);
```

But this will just escape the first occurrence of (.

**EDIT 2**

Maybe I should mention that my string could have these parentheses already escaped and, in this case, I don't want to escaped them again.

By the way, I need it working for both double and single quotes but I think that I can do that as long as I have a working example for one of them.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: I guess i don't understand do you want to add the escapes to the first string?

Comment: no he wants to escape parentheses that are inside quotes

Comment: @JohnConde I improved the question content in order to tell what I tried so far.

Comment: What do you think about situations like `"hi (text" here) and ("other "text)"`?

Comment: @inhan In my case, these situations should never occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for both single and double quotes:

```
$str = '"hi \(text here)" and (other text) come \'(again)\'';

$str = preg_replace_callback('`("|\').*?\1`', function ($matches) {
    return preg_replace('`(?<!\\\)[()]`', '\\\$0', $matches[0]);
}, $str);

echo $str;
```

output

```
"hi \(text here\)" and (other text) come '\(again\)'
```

It is for PHP >= 5.3. If you have a lower version (>=5) you have to replace the anonymous function in the callback with a separate function.

Comment: @CristianoSantos yes it does. But if you do not want that you may have to update your question.

Comment: @flec You don't need to escape parens inside a character group.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) for this;

```
// outputs: hi \(text here\) and \(other text\) come (again)
print preg_replace_callback('~"(.*?)"~', function($m) {
    return '"'. preg_replace('~([\(\)])~', '\\\$1', $m[1]) .'"';
}, '"hi (text here) and (other text)" come (again)');
```

What about already escaped strings;

```
// outputs: hi \(text here\) and \(other text\) come (again)
print preg_replace_callback('~"(.*?)"~', function($m) {
    return '"'. preg_replace('~(?:\\\?)([\(\)])~', '\\\$1', $m[1]) .'"';
}, '"hi \(text here\) and (other text)" come (again)');
```

Comment: Your output misses the quotes because you are only returning the replaced submatch.

Answer (score 1):

Given the string

```
$str = '"hi (text here) and (other text)" come (again) "maybe (to)morrow?" (yes)';
```

Iterative method

```
 for ($i=$q=0,$res='' ; $i<strlen($str) ; $i++) {
   if ($str[$i] == '"') $q ^= 1;
   elseif ($q && ($str[$i]=='(' || $str[$i]==')')) $res .= '\\';
   $res .= $str[$i];
 }

 echo "$res\n";
```

But if you're a fan of recursion

```
 function rec($i, $n, $q) {
   global $str;
   if ($i >= $n) return '';
   $c = $str[$i];
   if ($c == '"') $q ^= 1;
   elseif ($q && ($c == '(' || $c == ')')) $c = '\\' . $c;
   return $c . rec($i+1, $n, $q);
 }

 echo rec(0, strlen($str), 0) . "\n";
```

Result:

```
"hi \(text here\) and \(other text\)" come (again) "maybe \(to\)morrow?" (yes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it with the [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function.

```
$str = '"hi (text here) and (other text)" come (again)';
$escaped = preg_replace_callback('~(["\']).*?\1~','normalizeParens',$str);
// my original suggestion was '~(?<=").*?(?=")~' and I had to change it
// due to your 2nd edit in your question. But there's still a chance that
// both single and double quotes might exist in your string.

function normalizeParens($m) {
    return preg_replace('~(?<!\\\)[()]~','\\\$0',$m[0]);
    // replace parens without preceding backshashes
}
var_dump($str);
var_dump($escaped);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without nesting regex calls inside of regex calls.  Neither do I endorse a long winded loop with conditions and temporary variables.

The hero to call upon for this task is `\G` -- the "continue" metacharacter.  It allows to to start matching from on position in a string and continue matching from the position where the last match finished.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hcCCk))

```
$str = '"hi (text here) and (other text)" come (again) and "(again)", right?';

echo preg_replace(
         '~(?:\G(?!^)|"(?=[^"]+"))[^"()]*(?:"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\K[()])~',
         '\\\$0',
         $str
     );
```

Output:

```
"hi \(text here\) and \(other text\)" come (again) and "\(again\)", right?
```

Breakdown: ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EZ0Lgt/1))

```
(?:               #start noncapturing group 1
  \G(?!^)         #continue, do not match from start of string
  |               #OR
  "(?=[^"]+")     #match double quote then lookahead for the second double quote
)                 #end noncapturing group 1
[^"()]*           #match zero or more characters not (, ), or "
(?:               #start noncapturing group 2
  "(*SKIP)(*FAIL) #consume but do not replace
  |               #OR
  \K              #forget any previously matched characters
  [()]            #match an opening or closing parenthesis
)                 #end noncapturing group 2
```

This solution does not accommodate fringe scenarios when escaped characters should be disqualified from their normal meaning in the string/pattern.