# php -> preg_replace -> remove space ONLY between quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove space ONLY between quotes like:

```
$text = 'good with spaces "here all spaces should be removed" and here also good';
```

can someone help with a working piece of code ? I already tried:

```
$regex = '/(\".+?\")|\s/';
```

or

```
$regex = '/"(?!.?\s+.?)/';
```

without success, and I found a sample that works in the wrong direction :-(
[Removing whitespace-characters, except inside quotation marks in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824964/removing-whitespace-characters-except-inside-quotation-marks-in-php) but I can't change it.

thx Newi

Comment: Show what you have already tried, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: I think the OP wants to turn `$text = 'good with spaces "here all spaces should be removed" and here also good';` into `$text = 'good with spaces "hereallspacesshouldberemoved" and here also good';`

Comment: [Replace all occurences of char inside quotes on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14688462/2943403)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of problem are easily solved with `preg_replace_callback`. The idea consists to extract the substring between quotes and then to edit it in the callback function:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('~"[^"]*"~', function ($m) {
    return preg_replace('~\s~', '#', $m[0]);
}, $text);
```

It's the most simple way.

---

It's more complicated to do it with a single pattern with `preg_replace` but it's possible:

```
$text = preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!\A)|")[^"\s]*\K(?:\s|"(*SKIP)(*F))~', '#', $text);
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/PoJwXj/1)

Pattern details:

```
(?:
    \G (?!\A)  # match the next position after the last successful match
  |
    "          # or the opening double quote
)
[^"\s]*        # characters that aren't double quotes or a whitespaces
\K             # discard all characters matched before from the match result
(?:
    \s         # a whitespace
  |
    "           # or the closing quote
    (*SKIP)(*F) # force the pattern to fail and to skip the quote position
                # (this way, the closing quote isn't seen as an opening quote
                # in the second branch.)
)
```

This way uses the `\G` anchors to ensure that all matched whitespaces are between the quotes.

Edge cases:

- there's an orphan opening quote: In this case, all whitespaces from the last quote until the end of the string are replaced. But if you want you can change this behavior adding a lookahead to check if the closing quote exists:

  `~(?:\G(?!\A)|"(?=[^"]*"))[^"\s]*\K(?:\s|"(*SKIP)(*F))~`
- double quotes can contain escaped double quotes that have to be ignored: You have to describe escaped characters like this:

  `~(?:\G(?!\A)|")[^"\s\\\\]*+(?:\\\\\S[^"\s\\\\]*)*+(?:\\\\?\K\s|"(*SKIP)(*F))~`

---

Other strategy suggested by @revo: check if the number of remaining quotes at a position is odd or even using a lookahead:

```
\s(?=[^"]*+(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*+")
```

It is a short pattern, but it can be problematic with long strings since for each position with a whitespace you have to check the string until the last quote with the lookahead.

Comment: Great. There could be another approach in case of no quotes inside quotes: [`\h(?=[^"]*"[^"]*+(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*+\z)`](https://regex101.com/r/oN9mYH/1)

Answer (score 0):

See the following code snippet:

```
<?php
$text = 'good with spaces "here all spaces should be removed" and here also good';
echo "$text \n";
$regex = '/(\".+?\")|\s/';
$regex = '/"(?!.?\s+.?)/';
$text = preg_replace($regex,'', $text);
echo "$text \n";
?>
```

I found [a sample that works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824964/removing-whitespace-characters-except-inside-quotation-marks-in-php) in the wrong direction :-(

---

@Graham: correct

```
$text = 'good with spaces "here all spaces should be removed" and here also good'
should be 
$text = 'good with spaces "hereallspacesshouldberemoved" and here also good';
```

Comment: These kinds of observations are best done in edits to the original question; answers are for offering working solutions to the question.